# IE 11 addClass + removeClass

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I can not get this code to work on Internet Explorer 11. I know this segment is causing the problem. If I upload my file with this code active, IE 11 dispays entire sections of my website completely blank. Without it, it will display the information on my site, but it obviously doesn't function the same.

I have looked up various features on http://caniuse.com/, according to it, there is only partial support for removeClass and addClass, which may be the problem. Is there some sort of plugin or a different command to make this compatible with IE 11?

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    var ImageContainer = $('.tabs > div'),
    hash = window.location.hash !== '' ? window.location.hash: '#about';

    console.log(hash);

    ImageContainer.hide();
    ImageContainer.filter(hash).show();
    $('<img/>').removeClass('selected');
    $('a[href="' + hash + '"]', '.ImageContainer').addClass('selected');
}).trigger('hashchange');
```

EDIT - MARKUP

```
<div class="tabs">

<div id="about">    
<h3>Headline</h3>
<p>Body Text</p>
</div>

<div id="first">
<h3>Different Headline</h3>
<p>Different Body Copy</p>
</div>

</div>

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

<div class="ImageContainer">
    <div id="Color">
    <h2>Headline</h2> 
</div>

<div class="photo grow">  
     <a href="#first" id="1">    
     <img src="" />
     </a>
     </div>

 <div class="ImageFooter" id="Purple">
     <p class="ImageContainerP">Below Text</p>
     </div>
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com doesn't give information about browser support for jQuery, that can be found at [jQuery](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)

Comment: "_I have looked up various jquery commands on http://caniuse.com/_" O.o - jQuery methods are not part of the site as the site only lists native features.

Comment: @GeorgeLee thanks for the direction. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on how IE treats hash. It doesn't default to empty string like the other browsers, it defaults to '#'. Also rather than setting hash, you should set location for reliability in IE.

```
hash = window.location.hash !== '' ? window.location.hash: '#about';
```

becomes

```
hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash !== '' || hash !== '#') {
   hash = '#about';
   window.location = hash;
}
```

The markup was not rendering because it was not resetting the hash on entry and giving an error message that '#' was not a valid selector for the filter.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should use correct selector:

For this HTML:

```
<div class="ImageContainer">
    <a href="#1234"><img class="selected" src="" /></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('img').removeClass('selected');
$('a[href="#1234"]', '.ImageContainer').addClass('selected');
```

OUTPUT:

```
<div class="ImageContainer">
    <a href="#1234" class="selected"><img src="" class=""></a>
</div>
```

Tested on IE 11 and FF 42:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/h1xtty4n/

Comment: Thanks for the help. This, unfortunately, hasn't solved my problem but has helped narrow down the search. My issue is probably hiding somewhere in CSS or the source code. This worked fine for me in my own fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cef1ydna/ Thanks again!