# If IE, run this script, else, run this script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I've trying to load one script on IE, and another script for every other browser. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Navigation-Toggle-IE.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Navigation-Toggle.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

This statement just makes my page distort on Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Does anyone have any insight or resources?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Thanks! Checking it out now

Comment: Conditional Comments were removed from Internet Explorer 10. It's encouraged that you leverage modern standards in more recent versions of Internet Explorer, and Microsoft Edge. If you identify any shortcomings of the browsers, I'm happy to help, as a Microsoft Edge team member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't close the conditional comment on ie or the other browsers can read it. Also remember this only works on ie9 and below.

```
<!--[if IE]
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Navigation-Toggle-IE.js"></script>
[endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Navigation-Toggle.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Uh-oh...I'm aiming to get it to work on more recent versions of IE. I'm trying to get IE to read more script (marked -IE) and all other browsers to read a different version of that script.

Comment: If I may ask what is the reason for this? IE 10+ are treated as first class and don't usually need the work arounds in the older browsers. It was this reason that Microsoft removed it. (Remember that on an intranet site IE is opt-out of quirks mode by using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />, many times developers are chasing down IE bugs that are a result of this).

Comment: My problem is that sections of my website are not showing on IE 11 (see this link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675219/ie-11-addclass-removeclass). There seems to be one segment of code causing this - it's probably conflicting with something else in my site. Whether the meta tag is in my head or not doesn't make a difference (I've tested it). I thought the best solution for me was to simply not add that piece of code on internet explorer, but have it active for all other browsers. It won't have the same functionality on Internet Explorer, but at least users can see it.

Comment: I read the other link and understand the issue now. It is very difficult to reliably detect IE11. We used to be able to check if document.all existed and document.opera did not as they were the only browsers that supported that. It was removed in 11 though. Detection by user-agent is always a no no too. The best bet is to find the issue and fix it. I would be willing to help you debug it via skype call (@victoriafrench) or Google Hangouts (victoria dot french at cinecove dot com) if you like. It probably wouldn't take long to find and it frees up this board from the moderators locking it.

Comment: Sounds fantastic! Thank you so much! I've sent you a message via skype and look forward to speaking with you.

Comment: Glad I was able to help fix you :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of conditional comments for JavaScript objects, checking browser features  is usually more reliable.

I mean is instead of making 2 scripts, make one and change the functionality based on the detected browser.
Example:

```
var ie = 'ActiveXObject' in window;
var ielt9 = ie && !document.addEventListener; // ie8 and bellow

if (ie) {
 // do ie stuff
} else {
 // do other stuff
}
```