# Firefox hashchange

Tags: jquery, firefox, browser, hash

Upon testing my site in different browsers, I realized the back button in Firefox doesn't work for my website. I believe the hashchange code I am using is the cause:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

location.hash = '';

$(window).on('hashchange', function (){
    var ImageContainer=$('.tabs>div'),
    hash=window.location.hash;

if (hash===''||hash==='#'){
hash="#about";
window.location=hash;
}

    ImageContainer.hide();
    ImageContainer.filter(hash).show(); 
    $('img').removeClass('selected');
    $('a[href="#123456"]','.ImageContainer').addClass('selected');
}).trigger('hashchange');   
});
```

I've tried adding an additional plugin (http://benalman.com/), but it had no effect. This problem is exclusive to Firefox (IE11, Chrome, Opera, Safari work without issue.) I know the code is adding a blank hashchange (#about) to all my pages regardless of whether they have the hashchange function or not. It's setup to check like this to accommodate IE11 (see this post for more info: [IE 11 addClass + removeClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675219/ie-11-addclass-removeclass)) Does anyone have any ideas? Perhaps there's an additional line of code needed, or I could try changing the URL of the pages (That may cause more issues than it solves...I haven't explored that option fully yet.)

DELETED

```
window.location=hash;
```

REVISED

```
if (hash===''){
hash="#about";
}
```

The piece of code adding the # tag to the end of my URL is:

```
hash=window.location.hash;
```

I'm having trouble finding a substitute for this section that won't mess my site up. I've tried: window.back(1); but it causes glitches in my site.

Comment: How do you debug it? Any error in FF console? This looks suspicious to me: `window.location=hash;`

Comment: There aren't any errors in FF console. You were right about that window.location=hash; being suspicious though. I have modified my code, the back button works slightly better, but I have to press it 2 times to get Firefox to go back. It still displays a # at the end of the URL, press back once, it disappears, press back again and it will go back the page.